# Javascript manipulando através de um botão vários trechos de texto Html

Tags: javascript, button

O código abaixo funciona para um ID especifico, eu precisava de um código que afeta-se vários elementos e não apenas um id especifico.

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor clique em [edit] e coloque um exemplo do HTML e de quais elementos você quer modificar de uma vez. Tem várias formas de fazer, mas vai depender da estrutura da página e de quais elementos quer pegar

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece pois no `html` o `id` é para dar um *indentificador* para apenas 1 elemento, para selecionar varios deles, uma das maneiras é utilizar o *atríbuto* `class`.

O código ficaria assim:

```html
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
          for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
              if (x[i].style.display === "none") {
                x[i].style.display = "block";
              } else {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
              }
            }
        } 
</script>    
</head>
<body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
        
        <div class="myClass">
          This is my DIV element.
        </div>
        <div class="myClass">
          This is my other DIV element.
        </div>
        <div class="myClass">
          This is my new DIV element.
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: "*para selecionar varios deles, deve se usar o atríbuto class*" - isso dá a entender que usar classes é a única forma, mas não é. Por exemplo, com `querySelectorAll` pode-se usar vários critérios diferentes (por nome da tag, por nome/valor dos atributos, até mesmo por vários id's de uma vez, ou qualquer combinação destes, etc). De qualquer forma, sem saber a estrutura do HTML e quais elementos se quer pegar, qualquer resposta será um palpite (pedi para que o autor da pergunta esclareça essas informações, pois sem isso não dá pra sugerir a melhor solução)

Comment: Obrigado, tinha esquecido do `querySelectorAll`, acabei de editar a resposta.

Comment: Eu tinha esquecido de adicionar um for, pois o `getElementsByClassName` retorna um `array` com os elementos, teste agora para ver se funciona

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu certo agora!